# What's wrong with my PDFs?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, debugging

I'm generating PDFs ([like this for example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j7mq9rbk7ehuol9/Notes.pdf?dl=0)) using LaTeX, and suddenly code that has worked for years is generating PDFs that either fail to display or crash normal PDF readers (even [PDF Expert](https://pdfexpert.com)).

The code I'm using is highly customized and difficult to debug, and I'm not getting any error messages or [log entries](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q6tt431y0nmi6qh/Notes.log?dl=0) that reveal what's going wrong (the file generation succeeds and is at least *partially* or *occasionally* readable), so my sense is that examining the generated PDF itself directly may shed light on the issue, especially since that's where it manifests: in viewers and other software that attempts to display it.

Is there anything clearly wrong with this PDF that could be causing viewers to choke or crash? If so, is there a likely source for those glitches (and is there a likely LaTeX-related cause). I have *no issues* with PDFs that have been generated in other ways, or with PDFs that were generated earlier from the same code.

---

Note that the example may work fine in browsers (at least for some) and in simple viewers (e.g. preview or view-only apps). I'm most interested to hear if the errors appear in Preview on macOS, specifically (for others, as it does for me) or in PDF Expert (which manages to view the file for a bit, but hangs eventually if one attempts to close the tab showing the document).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67425/discussion-on-question-by-orome-whats-wrong-with-my-pdfs).

Comment: As you wished, I removed the comments. They are still in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67425/discussion-on-question-by-orome-whats-wrong-with-my-pdfs) to discuss on it, if needed. It would be great if you would edit your question to make clear, that it goes to the right direction then (you may summarize what's not the right direction, from the comments).